# How to query from a Directed Acyclic Graph with exclusive subsets

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, dependency-management, directed-acyclic-graphs

**Question in abstract terms:**

I have a directed acyclic graph (DAG) which contains subsets of vertices which are exclusive when queried (only one item per subset should be present in the query's results). When I query the graph structure I would like to get the set of vertices which flow from a given vertex while only selecting a single item from known subsets of the vertices in the graph.

**Question in concrete terms:**

I have a DAG that stores my assemblies(vertices) and their dependencies(edges). Given an assembly or set of assemblies I need to query to get the set of all involved assemblies and their dependencies. The difficult part is that each assembly has multiple versions and only one instance of an assembly can be loaded into a process. The dependencies for a given assembly change between the various versions of the assembly.

*Is there a name for this problem or group of problems? A standard algorithm I can research to find a solution?*

---

Possible solution areas:

A *transitive closure* seems close to a good solution but the item chosen from the subset (assembly version) will change depending on the path taken through the graph, possibly through multiple branches so you would almost need to trace the path taken through the graph to generate the transitive closure.

A *graph database* might be able to help out quite a bit but we want to avoid going down that road right now unless we absolutely have to.

Comment: +1 for a well formulated question and the unicorn :)

Comment: I'm not that sure the question is formulated clearly. If you speak about DAG then you should say in graph terminology - what is vertex, what is edge, and what output you expect. All this is missing in your question.

Comment: Are multiple versions of the same dependency stored as a single dependency or multiple dependencies?

Comment: @Bryan I added the [tag:dependency-management] tag to attract people familiar with the concrete question, as they may have a number of alternatives.

Comment: The graph is set up with a given assembly version as a vertex and the dependency as an edge. The versions are combined into sets (all of the versions of a given assembly) by a separate data structure. The output should be a set of assembly versions with only one version of each assembly.

Comment: @Bryan, OK, now its much more clearer.

Comment: If I understand correctly, your solution will most likey not be unique. Consider the dependencies A->B, A->C, A->D and exclusive subsets {B,C} and {C,D}. Then, if the requested node is A, then both {B,D} and {C} would be both be valid solutions. Do you have any requirements on the solutions (e.g.: maximum/minimum size, etc...) or do you want to list all solutions?

Comment: Each of the versions include a version number, I'd just choose the latest version once I have a working set.

Comment: On the one hand, it seems like you are dealing with some kind of coloring problem because of the exclusion, but it isn't clear without knowing what other kinds of constraints you have.  With just the information you've given, it seems like removing all but one version can be done as a separate pass once you've found the set of vertices you are interested in, but I suspect you have another constraint, such as an assembly version can only be included in the output if a dependent assembly version is also in the output.

Comment: @Bryan: If that's the case, couldn't you just traverse the DAG starting from each of your source nodes (e.g.: via depth- or breadth-first search), collecting the list of all reachable nodes? Every time you come upon an assembly that you've seen before, keep the one with the highest version number.

Comment: @mhum The issue with that is that dependencies get added or removed with new versions. So version 1 of assembly A [A1] might rely on one of versions 1-3 of assembly B[B1-3] but A2 might rely on B4 only so if A1 is in the result set B4 can't be.

Comment: @BryanAnderson Ah. I fear I may have misunderstood your problem statement. When you said "only selecting a single item from known subsets of the vertices", I interpreted this to mean (in your most recent example) that at most one item in the subset {A1, A2} and at most one item of the subset {B1, B2, B3, B4} could be in the result set. But, you're saying that there can be some kind of interaction between these two subsets which prevent A1 and B4 from appearing together in the result set. Could you please clarify this restriction?

Comment: @mhum Correct, depending on the selection from group A some members of group B might become invalid.

Comment: @BryanAnderson Can you please describe more clearly how selections from group A affect selections from group B? I am still unable to infer from either your original problem statement nor from your subsequent comments what the exact requirements of the result set are.

Comment: @mhum Let's say assembly A version 1 [A1] depends on assembly B version 1 [B1], A2 depends on B2, and so on. If I select a certain A into my result set then only its corresponding B can be selected into the result set. If I select A2 I can not select B1. Most of the time an assembly A will depend on some range of assemblies B and there will be another assembly C that also depends on some set of B so I would need to say, find the set of B such that A2 and C3's dependencies are satisfied. Once I have that set of B I'd just choose the one with the highest version number.

Comment: @BryanAnderson Ok. This is a little more clear. A few more questions: In this instance, if you select A1, is it required that B1 be selected? I would assume yes. If A1 were dependent on B1 and B2, and you selected A1, is the idea that you would need to select exactly one of {B1, B2}?

Comment: @BryanAnderson In that case, what happens if you have the following chain of dependencies (and no others): A1 -> B1 -> A2 -> C1. Granted, your real-life data might not have such situations, but if that's the case, we need to be precise about what exactly is going on here.

Comment: @mhum There would be a cycle then. I guess the anti-cycle stipulation is a little stronger than with a normal DAG as there also can not be a cycle within the set, i.e. there can not exist a path from one A to another(or the same) A in the graph.

Comment: @BryanAnderson Ok. There may also be issues when you have situations like this: A1 -> B2, B1 -> A2 and the query set includes {A1, B1}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the set of vertices that flow from a given choice looks confusing because there is actually an underlying optimisation or satisfaction problem: given an assembly A, you can satisfy its dependencies via B1 or B2 or B3, and each of those choices then has its own knock-on consequences.

If we view this as a logic satisfaction problem, then we could consider a problem where assemblies come in only two versions, e.g. A1 or A2. Then a clause such as (a or b or not c) would translate to an upper-level assembly that required A1 or B1 or C2 - possibly indirectly via X1, X2 and X3 - and a conjunction of clauses would translate to an upper-upper level assembly that required all of the upper-level assemblies. So I think that if you could solve the general problem efficiently you could solve 3-SAT efficiently, and then P = NP.

Curiously, if you don't have the restriction that you are allowed only one assembly of each type (A1 or A2 or A3 but more than one at a time) then the problem translates very easily into Horn clauses (Knuth Vol 4 section 7.1.1 P 57) for which the satisfiability problem can be solved efficiently. To do this, you work with the inverse of the natural variables, so that X1 means that A1 is not included. Then if you treat the Horn clause version as a way of relaxing your problem, by ignoring the constraint that at most one version of each assembly can be supported, what you get is a mechanism for telling you that some assembly version A1 *cannot* be in the solution, because X1 = not A1 is true in the core of the Horn solution, and therefore true in every satisfying assignment.

Comment: Thanks, knowing it's a P = NP problem I'll use the graph the check the sets of assemblies I deploy to make sure they're valid and just store a working set of assemblies to query rather than having it be done dynamically.